# Another Quick Trig Question

Tags: trigonometry

So I am asked to find the sum of all solutions to

$\sin(3x) = \cos(6x)$, $x\in[0,2\pi)$

I'm trying to turn everything in terms of sine, so I do:

$\sin(3x) = 1-2\sin^2(6x)$

However, my book says the correct way to begin this is:

$\sin(3x) = 1-2\sin^2(3x)$

Why is it $1-2\sin^2(3x)$ instead of $1-2\sin^2(6x)$ if I want it to be equivalent to $\cos(6x)$? I thought the argument stays the same when you convert? Very confused.

Comment: Your downvote most likely comes from not using proper $\LaTeX$ formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the correct trigonometric identity named [Double-angle formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle_formulae) is

$$\cos 2x = 1-2\sin^2\color{red}x\implies \cos 6x = 1-2\sin^2\color{red}{3x}$$

Comment: ohh thank you so much!

Comment: It is the double angle  identity, it can be proved. You should find it in your material. I've added a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it $1−2\sin^2(3x)$ instead of $1−2\sin^2(6x)$ if I want it to be equivalent to $\cos(6x)$?

One can rewrite $\cos(6x)$ as $\cos(3x+3x)$. By the [trigonometric addition formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html) for cosine,

$$\cos(3x+3x)=\cos(3x)\cos(3x)-\sin(3x)\sin(3x)=\cos^2(3x)-\sin^2(3x)\;\;(1).$$

If one look at a proof of the fact that $\sin^2(\color{orange}x)+\cos^2(\color{orange}x)=1$, exempli gratia [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-fAx_96lgw), one can deduce that the same must be true for not only $\color{orange}x$ but also for $3x$, so $\sin^2(3x)+\cos^2(3x)=1$ (look [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/60gjatqtfx) if you still do not understand). Therefore,

$$\cos^2(3x)=1-\sin^2(3x)\;\;(2).$$

By inserting $(2)$ into $(1)$, one get that

$$1-\sin^2(3x)-\sin^2(3x)=1-2\sin(3x).$$ This means that $\cos(6x)=1-2\sin(3x)$. Therefore,

$$\sin(3x)=1-2\sin(3x).$$